# It suits him, to mean: That him to a tee

Tags: word-usage, idiomatic-language

There are three people A, B and C. A makes a comment about a thing, this reminds B of a parson C. So he says:

> What you said suits C. (this means that what A said is exactly what C looks like, and this may look good or not.)

Like : That's C to a tee.

So is the use of  "suit" natural?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word "suit" as a verb means "to meet the requirements of" or "to be appropriate for". It is a straightforward use of the dictionary definition to say, "Your comment describes Bob perfectly. What you said suits him very well."

We commonly say that something "fits X to a tee", meaning that it fits him very well. You can say this in a literal sense, like, "that shirt fits Bob to a tee", or in a more figurative sense, "Bob's new job is exactly the kind of job he wanted. The job fits him to a tee."

"It's him to a tee" is a short-hand version of this.

Both are common and "natural", yes.

Answer (score 1):

"It suits him" and "that's him to a tee" are similar but not exactly the same:

> "It suits him" implies that the thing being discussed or talked about is something appropriate for him.
>
> "that's him to a tee" means that something is correct for you, down to the smallest detail

That being said, in this context, I would agree that it's natural to use

Comment: So "it suits him" is natural,right?

Comment: @It'saboutEnglish "That being said, in this context, I would agree that it's natural to use" - yes